# where is the servlet-api.jar in glassfish installation?

Tags: jar, glassfish

We are migrating our project from the Sun App server to Glassfish. For compilation we need the classpath to be set to the servlet-api.jar which is found in the servlet container. Where in the Glassfish installation can I find these jars?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess you want to use Glassfish 3 or higher.

You can find the servlet-api in

```
$GLASSFISH_HOME\glassfish\modules\javax.servlet-api.jar
```

in Glassfish 3 and 4.